# Managing Lots of Azure Queues

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-queues

Part of my application includes a "chat" system. I maintain a queue for each user. Messages to the user are placed in the queue, and the user's software periodically polls a rest service for new messages, at which point the queue is pumped for messages, and they are returned to the user.

The system is very simple, works well, and does all I need it to do.

My problem is; I have hundreds (and soon thousands) of queues cluttering up the queue list for the application.

I have other queues as well, and it's disconcerting to me that I can't "organize" them like I can with things in blob storage.

Am I missing something, or should I just ignore the queue list, and rely on the fact that I'm properly managing the creation and deletion of queues as users come and go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would just ignore the fact that the list is cluttered. Blobs live in containers, but queues don't have a container. Everything's one flat list.

Unless you want to query the queues somehow, the flat list shouldn't bother you. If you do need to query queues (like "most recently used" or something like that), you'll probably need to keep a table with the list of queues and some of their properties to make it easier to query.

Comment: That's pretty much what I thought... thanks for the confirmation :)